# selenium chromedriver authentication proxy

Tags: java, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I need to connect to a proxy server with a
user name and password (i.e USERNAME:PASSWD@IP:PORT)
with chromedriver webdriver in selenium 2 in java.
I've found how to do it without using a user name 
and password, but haven't found a way to do it with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to connect to a proxy server with a user name and password is by using the tool `sshuttle` running on your machine. This tool allows you to create a connection to your proxy server using SSH, and then route all of your traffic.

```
$ sshuttle -r username@remotehost 0.0.0.0/0
```

See https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html for further information.

Another approach is to add a Chrome extension. This approach is a bit more complex, but it allows you to use the Chrome WebDriver without any tools running in the background. You would need to create a Chrome extension by including two files in an archive named `proxy.zip`: `Background.js` and `manifest.js`.

**Background.js**:

```js
var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "YOUR_PROXY_ADDRESS",
            port: parseInt(PROXY_PORT)
        },
        bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
    }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({ value: config, scope: "regular" }, function () { });
function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "PROXY_USERNAME",
            password: "PROXY_PASSWORD"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    callbackFn,
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    ['blocking']
);
```

**manifest.js**:

```js
var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "YOUR_PROXY_ADDRESS",
            port: parseInt(PROXY_PORT)
        },
        bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
    }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({ value: config, scope: "regular" }, function () { });
function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "PROXY_USERNAME",
            password: "PROXY_PASSWORD"
        }{
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "manifest_version": 3,
            "name": "Chrome Proxy",
            "permissions": [
            "Proxy",
            "Tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "Storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
            ],
            "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
            },
            "Minimum_chrome_version":"76.0.0"
            }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    callbackFn,
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    ['blocking']
);
```

Then you would need to add the Chrome extension to the ChromeOptions using the `addExtension` method:

```java
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addExtensions("proxy.zip");
```

The details are described (for Python) on the page: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/set-proxy-in-selenium