# How to use authenticated proxy in selenium chromedriver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After searching for many hours I am starting to think this is impossible.

I need to run Chrome through selenium using different authenticated (not public) proxy's for each run.

```
PROXY_IP = "<some IP address>"
UID = "<the user id>"
PWD = "<the password">

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=%s:%s@%s" % (UID,PWD,PROXY_IP))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=".\\driver\\chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=options)
driver.get("<site URL>")
```

Chrome will fire-up and display the error:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES
```

If I use a public proxy requiring no authentication like this...

```
PROXY_IP = "<public proxy IP address>"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=%s" % PROXY_IP)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=".\\driver\\chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=options)
driver.get("<site URL>")
```

...it runs just fine and displays the site while using the proxy.

I also tried a variant with `http://` in front of the user ID:

```
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://%s:%s@%s" % (UID,PWD,PROXY_IP))
```

The fact that I have searched far and wide and haven't found a solution leads me to believe none might exist.

I did find this but I can't make sense out of it:

[selenium chromedriver authentication proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033981/selenium-chromedriver-authentication-proxy)

Not sure what `browswermob-proxy` is or is supposed to do or how to implement and test in Python.  I hate piling up band-aid solutions unless they are absolutely necessary.

EDIT (08NOV21):

I have been away from using Selenium for many years.  Because of this I now lack the context (and time, sorry) to go through the newer answers being provided and mark one as the solution to this problem.  Does SO have a mechanism one could use to effectively delegate this function to someone who might be a current practitioner with expertise in this domain?

Comment: I've just submitted a bug report. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1605

Comment: any update/solution?

Answer (score 24):

To use proxies with auth in python selenium you can use [seleniumwire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire).

Fistly, install it with `pip install selenium-wire`

Then import webdriver from seleniumwire instead selenium

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://username:password@host:port', 
        'https': 'https://username:password@host:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1' # excludes
    }
}
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_driver, seleniumwire_options=options)
```

Now you can use your browser instance exact the same way as selenium: `browser.get('https://api.ipify.org')` and so on...

Comment: Can i update proxy option later for same webdriver instance?

Comment: @TaimurSaeed, sorry but actually I do not know. Need to test it

Comment: @Blackster I have tested it, and you can't change the configuration once an instance is created. The work around is to create a new driver instance with different configuration

Answer (score 4):

I have checked for most of the solutions on the web and for none of them authentication via chrome/firefox desired capabilities is working. Check this link: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/324. Finally the temporary solution is to whitelist your IP address with the proxy provider.

Comment: whitelisting it not a solution if username contains parameters

Comment: +1 for whitelisting, most proxy providers wouldn't require authentication if you whitelist your IP in their dashboard. Tested with oxylabs.io

Answer (score 3):

I could not find any solution for chrome. We can not add extensions with `headless` option. 
I am using Heroku with [chrome-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome). There are following options

1. Use `xvfb` instead of headless options and install extension
2. Use local proxy forwarder that forwards traffic to authenticated proxy; we can use [Squid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199424/squid-forward-to-another-proxy-with-authentication-details-for-the-parent-prox), mitProxy, or something like [proxy-login-automator](https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator)

Instead of these workaround I switched to Firefox where i was able to fill Username and Password on Proxy authentication Pop-up. Like given below. Following code is for Ruby using Capybara. You should be able to do something like this on your platform

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.send_keys('proxy-username' + Selenium::WebDriver::Keys::KEYS[:tab] + 'my-password')
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://gist.github.com/rajat-np/5d901702a33e7b4b5132b1acee5d778e) is the best solution I found and is the ONLY one that worked - all other answers on this question are outdated. It basically generates an auth extension for Chrome on the fly. Simply use the function as defined in the script as follows:

```py
driver = proxy_chrome(host, port, username, password)
driver.get("http://www.icanhazip.com/")
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/")
print('Terminated without issues.')
```

Note that this doesn't work with the --headless option. However, on Linux, you can simply use the x virtual frame buffer to simulate that. It's as easy as this in python:

```py
import xvfbwrapper
x = xvfbwrapper.Xvfb()
x.start()
```

Comment: Simple example on how to use xvfbwrapper: https://gist.github.com/cgoldberg/4151516

Comment: Also make sure to create an empty directory named 'extension' in case you use the proxy.py file linked to above, this is where the plugin file proxy_auth_plugin.zip will be stored. Moreover, host, username and password are strings, but port needs to be passed as an int.

Answer (score 2):

after trying many solutions that didn't actually work properly, i finally managed to set the authenticated proxy using the suggested extension from previous  answers.
what you need to do is to enter this link:

http://crxextractor.com/
and paste this url:
https://www.crx4chrome.com/crx/1446/

It will let you download the extention as a .crx file without installing it.
than i used this code:

```
proxy = {'address': 'pr.oxylabs.io:7777',
     'username': 'USERNAME',
     'password': 'PASSWORD'}

capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
capabilities['proxy'] = {'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
                         'httpProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'ftpProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'sslProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'noProxy': '',
                         'class': "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
                         'autodetect': False,
                         'socksUsername': proxy['username'],
                         'socksPassword': proxy['password']}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension("./extension_2_0_0_0.crx")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_PATH, desired_capabilities=capabilities, chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: This solution requires manual entry of the credentials the first time it's run.

Answer (score 2):

If you have permanent IP address (e.g. by leasing a machine in the cloud) you can contact  your proxy provider to access the proxy server with your IP instead of the user and password. In my experience that's easier.

If that's not possible, the other solution is:

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
pip install selenium-wire
```

Then set up proxy credentials using the 'proxy' key of a dictionary passed `seleniumwire_options` argument:

```
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome

options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://user:pass@ip:port',
        'https': 'https://user:pass@ip:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

driver = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Please read my edit with regards to no-longer being in a position to  evaluate answers.  Still, I hope your answer and those of others might help those with similar issues.  It might very well help me in the future if I ever come back to this domain.

Comment: That's why I did it.

Comment: how can I pass username and password in second method you told without seleniumwire

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching extensively. This is what it works for me

```
    PROXY_HOST = 'FILL IN'  # rotating proxy or host
    PROXY_PORT = 8080 # port
    PROXY_USER = 'FILL IN' # username
    PROXY_PASS = 'FILL IN' # password
    http_proxies = { 'https' : 'http://' + PROXY_USER + ':' + PROXY_PASS + '@' + PROXY_HOST + ':' + str(PROXY_PORT) }

    manifest_json = """
    {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Chrome Proxy",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
    }
    """

    background_js = """
    var config = {
            mode: "fixed_servers",
            rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: "%s",
                port: parseInt(%s)
            },
            bypassList: ["localhost"]
            }
        };

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

    function callbackFn(details) {
        return {
            authCredentials: {
                username: "%s",
                password: "%s"
            }
        };
    }

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                callbackFn,
                {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                ['blocking']
    );
    """ % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)




    def get_chromedriver(self, use_proxy=False):

        driver_path = 'FILL IN'
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        if use_proxy:
            pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

            with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
                zp.writestr("manifest.json", libshared.manifest_json)
                zp.writestr("background.js", libshared.background_js)
            chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path=driver_path,
            chrome_options=chrome_options)
        return driver
```

Answer (score 0):

I tryed lot of time to do the same.

Chrome is using only proxy of the OS where it is installed. You can check it by going to options-> find: proxy -> change proxy settings

So without additional addons and configuring this addons you cannot do this.

Or you can change your OS proxy settings -- this is much easier.

Also you can use phantomjs -- it have the same engine(WebKit) as chrome.
using something like this:

```
String PROXY = proxyIP + ":" + proxyPort;
String proxyAuth= proxyUser + ":" + proxyPass;
        OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
                    proxy.HttpProxy = PROXY;
                    proxy.FtpProxy = PROXY;
                    proxy.SslProxy = PROXY;
                    proxy.SocksProxy = PROXY;

    var serviceJS = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(phantomPath);
    serviceJS.AddArguments("--proxy=" + PROXY, "--proxy-type=http", "--proxy-auth=" + proxyAuth);
```

Comment: Chrome is NOT using OS proxy, you can easily set it by `options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=...")`

Comment: @Toolkit did you try this code and it has work? I tried to work with chrome proxy with such code and it's didn't work for me. The same is for FF browser.

Comment: yes adding proxy to ChromeDriver is trivial, `options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=http://proxy.com:111");`

Comment: I saw this and tried 2 years ago. More than 8 hrs tried different ways to work with proxy and no one was successful.

Comment: i am using it with C#

Comment: @Toolkit have you used socks5 proxy with authorization? I am having the same issue as the topic starter. If you have a working configuration, could you please post it somewhere?

Comment: At this point it is clear that Chrome with an un-authenticating proxy is trivial. However, an authenticated proxy is not. The question is specific on using an authenticated proxy. I have been unable to locate a solution barring using an outside plugin so far.

Comment: >  you can easily set it by options.AddArgument

It is not easy as you say. Already tried @Toolkit

Answer (score 0):

THis is a temporary solution might work in initial state:
Code is in Python:
Download the plugin first from chrome plugin store : Proxy-Auto-Auth_v2.0.crx

```
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_extension("./Proxy-Auto-Auth_v2.0.crx")) #this will provide you a window to enter user name and proxy 
        driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=selenium_server,desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())

        or 

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```