# How to set SOCKS5 proxy with auth for Chrome in selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use SOCKS5 proxy provided by PIA (https://www.privateinternetaccess.com). I generated user/pass for SOCKS5 on their site, but I can't use this information, since I don't know where to put it. I tried using `ChromeOptions`, but it's not working.

```
def create_browser(self, proxy):
    """
    proxy = "xGeneratedUser:GeneratedPass@proxy-nl.privateinternetaccess.com:1080"
    """
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if proxy:
        chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://" + proxy)
    try:
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.browser.set_window_size(800, 600)
    except Exception as error:
        return False
```

Comment: Well, not sure I'm helping, but just know [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a good and quick way to setup a http to socks5 proxy. You just have to set Chrome proxy to you local http to socks5 proxy.

Comment: I've answered your question, also a recommendation is to use PhantomJS instead of GoogleChrome driver since it uses a little bit more space/memory/cpu.

Answer (score 2):

I am stumping here too.
I also want to use auth proxy in the chrome webdriver of selenium.
I have tried use httpProxy or PAC, in which we cannot use username and password.

And then I saw the  `socksUsername` and `socksPassword` but it is still useless.
Because the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: proxy
from invalid argument: Specifying 'socksProxy' requires an integer for 'socksVersion'
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)
```

I found [chrome code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/capabilities.cc#336) said need the `socksProxy` key, but the current selenium is not support socksProxy, [see selenium code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/proxy.py#L96).

So I have to choose other way:

- set http_proxy in PATH, with `export http_proxy=http://username@pass:host:port`
- [use extension to hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451190/how-to-use-authenticated-proxy-in-selenium-chromedriver)

**UPDATE**:
**Finally**, I use [pproxy](https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy) make as a  proxy redirector on local.

```
# pproxy -r ${HTTP_PROXY}\#${PROXY_AUTH} -l http://:8080 -v
# 1.2.3.4:1234 is remote address:port, username and password is used auth for remote proxy.

 pproxy -r http://1.2.3.4:1234\#username:password  -l http://:8080 -v
```

So now your can connect to your localhost:8080 without auth.

Comment: the solution with the pproxy looks like the easiest and the clean one

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles on this...

I was trying to connect with a socks5 proxy with selenium and believe the issue was that the proxy requires user/pass auth, and since I was using the chromedriver it did not work because chrome does not natively support this.

Try connecting with a socks5 proxy that does not require auth or finding a driver that supports this - not aware of which/what this might be though.

Answer (score 0):

**selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver**

```
WebDriver(executable_path='chromedriver', port=0, chrome_options=None, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None)
```

Args :

- `executable_path` - path to the executable. If the default is used it
  assumes the executable is in the $PATH
- `port` - port you would like the service to run, if left as 0, a free
  port will be found.
- `desired_capabilities`: Dictionary object with non-browser specific
  capabilities only, such as “proxy” or “loggingPref”.
- `chrome_options`: this takes an instance of ChromeOptions

You may follow the table from below URL to write a proxy dictionary object for desired_capabilities.
[DesiredCapabilities - Proxy JSON Object](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#proxy-json-object)

Comment: Already tried both `chrome_options` and `desired_capabilities`, but no luck.

Comment: Well, found that SOCKS Authentication is not implemented in Chrome. Socks_Proxy removed in Proxy manual setting on chrome_options and desired_capabilities even, only http/ftp/ssl available. Maybe try other browser.

Answer (score 0):

## You can try following alternative : -

- In your `.bashrc` set `proxy` that will be used by chrome itself :-

  ```
  export http_proxy="xGeneratedUser:GeneratedPass@proxy-nl.privateinternetaccess.com:1080"

  export https_proxy="xGeneratedUser:GeneratedPass@proxy-nl.privateinternetaccess.com:1080"
  ```
- Otherwise you can use try this tool :- [proxy login automator](https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator)

### On windows, for http/https proxy with or without authentication, run one of the following commands in cmd.exe :-

```
set http_proxy=http://your_proxy:your_port
set http_proxy=http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
set https_proxy=https://your_proxy:your_port
set https_proxy=https://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: OS in use is Windows, not Linux, so this won't help.

Comment: For setting environment variables on windows see [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html)

Comment: Doesn't work either. Tried both solutions with user/pass data, but it can't resolve proxy auth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this:

var client = require('webdriverio').remote({
    host: 'username:password@127.0.0.1'
    port: 1234,
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
})

Comment: This question is for `Python`, not for `java`.