# How to set proxy AUTHENTICATION username:password using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy

I am using:

- Selenium 4
- python 3.7
- Firefox webdriver

I need to verify the username and password for my current project. I've been working day and night for days and I can't solve this problem. I've found a few extension on the internet, but it's from '13 year and I guess that's why it doesn't work. You can also see other methods I've tried below.

But doesn't work, because Proxy Authentication is not working anymore due to the Selenium bug..

```
alert_popup = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alert_popup.send_keys(
        "{username}{tab}{password}{tab}".format(
            username=proxy_username, tab=Keys.TAB, password=proxy_password
    )
)
alert_popup.accept()
```

I wanted to create a profile and save the proxy information manually and start selenium with that profile. However, firefox does not allow user name and password to be entered manually.

Comment: Apparently [selenium wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire) can do proxy auth, I'm not sure if I trust it though.

Comment: That's great! You might want to post an answer with how you did it for the next person.

Answer (score 2):

To use proxies with auth in python selenium you can use seleniumwire.

Fistly, install it with pip install selenium-wire

Then import webdriver from seleniumwire instead selenium

> Check the original Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451190/how-to-use-authenticated-proxy-in-selenium-chromedriver)

```
    from seleniumwire import webdriver
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://username:password@host:port', 
        'https': 'https://username:password@host:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1' # excludes
    }
}
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_driver, seleniumwire_options=options)
```

Comment: after alot of time searching why selenium is being very slow to load a page (15 sec) it turned out the problem was from seleniumwire, if your operation is time sensitive look for another solution