# Python selenium - Proxy connection with host, port, username, password

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

What I want:
A headless browser with private navigation and loggin to HTTPS proxy automatically

What I tried:
- PhantomJS -> Deprecated
- Google Chrome -> Proxy work but not with Headless
- Firefox -> Headless OK Private nav OK but can't use username and password in proxy connection

I have 4 variables, pxy["host"] ("xx.xx.xx.xx:xx"), pxy["username"], pxy["password"]

With Firefox I made some test

**Test 1 - capabilities with prompt**

```
capabilities['proxy'] = {'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
                'httpProxy': pxy["host"],
                'ftpProxy': pxy["host"],
                'sslProxy': pxy["host"],
                'noProxy': ''
                }
```

That's open a prompt in firefox to type login and password. I tried to use alert functions to send keys in alert form but it not work with firefox.
**Test 2 - capabilities with credentials**

```
capabilities['proxy'] = {'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
                'httpProxy': pxy["host"],
                'ftpProxy': pxy["host"],
                'sslProxy': pxy["host"],
                'socksUsername': pxy['login'],
                'socksPassword': pxy['password']
                }
```

That's make an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Invalid proxy configuration entry: socksPassword
```

**Test 3 - firefox preferences**

```
ip = pxy["host"].split(":")[0]
port = pxy["host"].split(":")[1]
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", ip)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", port)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username", pxy["login"])
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password", pxy["password"])
```

That's doesn't do anything, just keep my ip...
**Test 4 - Extensions ?**
I think I can use an extension like closeproxyauth.xpi (too old) to set my proxy but I'm not sure what I did.
When I use firefox_profile.add_extension(extension=extension_path), No extension appear in browser but path is correct.
I tried to use driver.install_addon(extension=extension_path, temporary=True) but he never found my path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dup of: [How to set proxy AUTHENTICATION username:password using Python/Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458816/how-to-set-proxy-authentication-usernamepassword-using-python-selenium?rq=1)

Selenium-wire: https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire

**Install selenium-wire**

```
pip install selenium-wire
```

**Import it**

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
```

**Auth to proxy**

```
options = {
'proxy': {
    'http': 'http://username:password@host:port',
    'https': 'https://username:password@host:port',
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

**Warning**
Take a look to the selenium-wire cache folder. I had a problem because it take all my disk space. You have to remove it sometimes in your script when you want.