# How do I set a proxy for chrome's webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I have already tried:
'''

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver',options=options) #<----- I used './chromedriver' to set a PATH
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

'''
The above code is taken from [how do i set proxy for chrome in python webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver).

I am getting an error from google chrome saying ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES, even when I am using public ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use authenticated proxy in selenium chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451190/how-to-use-authenticated-proxy-in-selenium-chromedriver)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
capabilities['proxy'] = {'proxyType': 'MANUAL','httpProxy': '23.23.23.23:3128','ftpProxy': '23.23.23.23:3128','sslProxy': '23.23.23.23:3128','noProxy': '','class': "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",'autodetect': False}
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--verbose')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver',options=chrome_options) #<----- I used './chromedriver' to set a PATH
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: But you never utilized `capabilities`? `webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)`