# Proxy not connecting in selenium in chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver, proxies

i was building a code to do something in selenium i have to connect to proxy to make it work i have some resendetial proxies but when i tried them on selenium it shows an error i have tried various drivers too

i have used the following codes:

```py
proxy_url = f"{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@{proxy_address}:{proxy_port}"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % proxy_url)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://idk.me')
print(driver.page_source)
time.sleep(50)
driver.quit()
```

when using this i get:"This site can’t be reached The web page at https://idk.me might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES
i also tried with firefox but the user and pass authentication keeped popping up

Comment: i have also tried:
```
proxy_url = "{}:{}@{}:{}".format(user, passs, ip, port)

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": proxy_url,
    "ftpProxy": proxy_url,
    "sslProxy": proxy_url,
    "noProxy": None,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect": False
}

url = 'https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

but it shows my ip instead of proxys

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Selenium with a proxy server that has authentication, you'll need to create a Chromium extension with the correct configuration, which is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35293284/7058266

Alternatively, you can use [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire) to run Selenium on a proxy server that has authentication, which is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56276796/7058266

Another way is to run a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) test with a command-line option that specifies a proxy server with authentication:

`pytest --proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@IP_ADDRESS:PORT`

(That option does the work of creating the Chromium extension for you.)

Comment: hey when i tried to use the first one it seems that i cant use headless mode with extension so i cant use it when i tried selenium-wire it shows me alot of error like http 404 not found etc. i didn tunderstanf the third one mind explaining?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/7058266 for the new headless mode if you want to use headless mode with extensions.

Comment: i have tried using --headless=chrome but shows same

Comment: You need ``--headless=new`` for Chrome 109 and above.

Comment: Just adding link to the [release notes](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/) of the *new Chrome headless mode* (without which you would get empty pages!) @MichaelMintz : let me appreciate some of your finest answers now for a while...